# How can I disable comment suggestions on my Facebook Page's live stream?

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages, facebook-comments, facebook-live-video

A page I manage publishes a recurrent live stream through the Facebook API every week. Lately I started noticing hundreds of comments from viewers containing only emojis. I think these are mainly the result of Facebook's comment suggestions (e.g. when watching my stream on a mobile device the comment section looks like the image below).

[image: Emoji suggestions in the comment section]

Can I somehow disable these suggestions for my stream so that people would be less inclined to post a comment that isn't really meaningful?